# Before vs. Until

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

To complete the blank in the following sentence, the *Answer Key* has offered ***until*** as the only correct answer. I wonder if it could be replaced with  **before** or  maybe even **both** options could be correct.

> We can't have dinner ......... all the guests arrive.

I have studied the answer given to a similar question but I didn't find it quite useful.

In case both answers are correct, what the difference(s) will be?

Comment: Yes, **before** is also an option in this context.

Comment: @Ronald Sole: What difference does it make in meaning then?

Comment: The meaning is the same - although I think it more likely that most people would use **until** in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Both "before" and "until" are correct here. "Before" speaks about the general situation meaning that while not all of the guests are present dinner cannot be started, but it may start not exactly immediately after they all have gather, whereas "until" mostly always requires a trigger, so once the guests have all gathered dinner can start.